# Unable to connect with MySQL running in Docker file: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'

Tags: python, mysql, docker

My team has developed a Flask App that uses Selenium to access several websites and is connected to a MySQL Database. All three are running in separate Docker containers.

However, I get following error when testing my Flask App:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)    
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()        
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/app/api.py", line 28, in data_takedown
    cursor, connection = get_db_connection()
  File "/app/api.py", line 20, in get_db_connection
    connection = MySQLdb.connect("privacy-mysql", "root", "DockerPasswort!", "privacydatabase")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 84, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)  
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 179, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'privacy-mysql' (-2)")
172.21.0.1 - - [16/Apr/2020 09:19:11] "POST /data_remove HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

This is the setup I have used in my Visual Studio Code Windows Subsystem for Linux Terminal on my Windows 10 computer:

```
docker run --name selenium-container -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 -v Desktop:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome-debug
docker run -d --name privacy-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=DockerPasswort! -e MYSQL_DATABASE=privacy-database -v "$(pwd)/db/db_records:/var/lib/mysq"l -v "$(pwd)/db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" --network privacy-network -dit -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
docker exec -it privacy-mysql bash
docker build -t privacy_api_image .
docker run -dit --name=privacy_api -e FLASK_APP=api.py -p 5000:5000 -v "$(pwd):/app" --network privacy-network privacy_api_image
docker logs -f privacy_api
```

Note that privacy_api is the container for the Flask app that can be run but throws the error when tested.

When running `docker exec -it privacy-mysql bash`, I first got this output: 
`Container da63bc4015c9cdb5cac71e8e0a9a8707491decdf2973f75ce28ee3d8e255259c is not running`. Thus, I followed [these instructions](https://forums.docker.com/t/run-command-in-stopped-container/343/6) to run the mysql container:

```
docker run -d --name privacy-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=DockerPasswort! -e MYSQL_DATABASE=privacy-database -v "$(pwd)/db/db_records:/var/lib/mysq"l -v "$(pwd)/db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" --network privacy-network -dit -p 3306:3306 mysql:latest --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
docker exec -it privacy-mysql bash
docker commit privacy-mysql myimage
sha256:420025006baadb7ce93d348e85993cad1ca29575de01f1977e604aca87f74879
docker run --name privacy myimage
```

This leads to the following Terminal output:

```
2020-04-16 09:17:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-04-16 09:17:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2020-04-16 09:17:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.19-1debian10 started.
2020-04-16 09:17:42+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files      
2020-04-16T09:17:42.408985Z 0 [Warning] 
[MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not 
using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. 
2020-04-16T09:17:42.409037Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) initializing of server in progress as process 43
2020-04-16T09:17:44.406732Z 5 [Warning] 
[MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2020-04-16 09:17:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized       
2020-04-16 09:17:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server        
2020-04-16T09:17:47.327022Z 0 [Warning] 
[MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not 
using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. 
2020-04-16T09:17:47.327105Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 93     
2020-04-16T09:17:47.794578Z 0 [Warning] 
[MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-04-16T09:17:47.798719Z 0 [Warning] 
[MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all 
OS users. Consider choosing a different 
directory.
2020-04-16T09:17:47.813848Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.19'  
socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.   
2020-04-16 09:17:47+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.        
2020-04-16T09:17:47.903473Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock'
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
2020-04-16 09:17:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database privacy-database

2020-04-16 09:17:49+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server        
2020-04-16T09:17:50.002102Z 11 [System] 
[MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user root. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.19).
2020-04-16T09:17:51.994762Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2020-04-16 09:17:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped

2020-04-16 09:17:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

2020-04-16T09:17:52.276573Z 0 [Warning] 
[MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not 
using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. 
2020-04-16T09:17:52.276651Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 1      
2020-04-16T09:17:52.687390Z 0 [Warning] 
[MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-04-16T09:17:52.692123Z 0 [Warning] 
[MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all 
OS users. Consider choosing a different 
directory.
2020-04-16T09:17:52.705752Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.19'  
socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.2020-04-16T09:17:52.821171Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

However, it still leads to the same `Unknown MySQL server host 'privacy-mysql' (-2)` error as above.

When running: `docker run -it 04683a5f1dfce359cf3b66fa82af4b016d19a8ee527c204354ff9c49249a915a bash`
I could access the bash but this shows that there seems to be a socket problem?:

```
root@70c4f452ed74:/# mysql -uroot -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
root@70c4f452ed74:/# /var/run/mysql start
bash: /var/run/mysql: No such file or directory
```

What else could I do to get the mysql running?
Thank you for your help!

-----------------------------EDIT 1----------------------------------------------

I also tried running (note using port 33060 instead 3306):

```
docker run --name selenium-container -d -p 4444:4444 -p 5900:5900 -v Desktop:/dev/shm selenium/standalone-chrome-debug
docker run -d --name privacy-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=DockerPasswort! -e MYSQL_DATABASE=privacy-database -v "$(pwd)/db/db_records:/var/lib/mysq"l -v "$(pwd)/db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d" --network privacy-network -dit -p 33060:3306 mysql:latest --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
docker commit privacy-mysql myimage
docker run --name privacy myimage
docker build -t privacy_api_image .
docker run -dit --name=privacy_api -e FLASK_APP=api.py -p 5000:5000 -v "$(pwd):/app" --network privacy-network privacy_api_image
docker logs -f privacy_api
```

But this leads to the same problem.

----------------------EDIT 2 --------------------------------------------
I just noticed that my root directory is as follows, maybe that is the reason for the error:

```
/root
----/main_api (folder)
    ---/api.py
    ---/Dockerfile
    ---/db_records  (folder)
    ---/docker_entrypoint-initdb.d  (folder)
---/db  (folder)
    ---/db_records  (folder)
    ---/docker_entrypoint-initdb.d  (folder)
```

Could it be that one part of the application is looking into the wrong db folder?

Comment: How are you configuring the location of the database in your application?  That seems to be your actual problem.  (I'm not sure what the `docker commit` sequence is about, but using that command at all usually isn't a good idea, and it won't include the database contents in the resulting image.)

Comment: In the root folder of the project, there is a `db` folder with `db_records` and `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` (In here is the SQL file to create the table) and this is the content of the `db_records` folder: https://imgur.com/a/0Qp98u3

Comment: I don't think you can put a PNG image file into the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` folder.  If it's important to your question, edit the question to add the text of the file.  But this seems like it's much more about your application's database setup than anything you've done to configure the database itself.

Comment: I don't have a png in there, its just a screenshot of the contents of the folder. But please see edit 2 of the question